# Combining thousands of audios in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, audio, ffmpeg, sox

I am getting E2BIG error when combining more than 50 audios using SOX is one go. Is there a way to handle this? I wish to combine thousands of audios in one go. One solution is to make a recursive batch function using SOX but looking for a simple solution.

Trying to implement this in NodeJs.

Appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: When you say "combine" do you want a sequential concatenation of one audio then the next and so on?

Comment: Hi @llogan. Yes. But all in one go if preferably in javascript.